# Looking for an example on how to embed a UITextField in a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a working UITableView with embedded UISwitch's inside. I am looking to have one row that instead uses a UITextField. It works when it firsts displays, but if I leave the screen and then come back, the label disappears and the UITextField gets pushed to the left.

Here is how it's displayed when I first go to the Settings tab:

[image]

When I flip over to the "Home" tab (or any other tab), and return to the Settings tab, I get the following:

[image]

I cannot figure out why.

Here is the code in question:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    var switchTag = 0
    var switchState = false

    switch indexPath.section {
    case SETTINGS_SECTION:
        cell.textLabel?.text =  settings[indexPath.row].name
        switchTag = settings[indexPath.row].tag
        switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "metric")
        break
    case UPLOADS_SECTION:
        cell.textLabel?.text =  uploads[indexPath.row].name
        switchTag = uploads[indexPath.row].tag
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "strava")
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "cycling_analytics")
        }
        break
    case DEVICES_SECTION:
        let device = devices[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text =  device.name
        switchTag = device.tag
        if deviceManager!.savedDevices.firstIndex(of: device.id) != nil {
            switchState = true
        } else {
            switchState = false
        }
        
    default:
        break
        
    }
    
    if switchTag == 2 {
        
        txtFTP = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 1, width: 50, height: 50))
        //txtFTP = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        cell.accessoryView = txtFTP
         
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let ftp = defaults.string(forKey: "FTP")

        if ftp == nil {
            txtFTP.placeholder = "FTP"
        } else {
            txtFTP.text = ftp
        }
        txtFTP.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        txtFTP.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        txtFTP.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        txtFTP.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        txtFTP.delegate = self
        txtFTP.keyboardType = .numberPad
        cell.accessoryView = txtFTP
        
    } else {
        let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
        switchView.setOn(switchState, animated: true)
        switchView.tag = switchTag // for detect which row switch Changed
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell.accessoryView = switchView
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

---

I solved this problem by first following the guide here: https://programmingwithswift.com/create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-swift/

I created a new nib in the story builder, then created the swift file that represents that new custom cell (as done in the above link).

Then I changed the above code to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    var switchTag = 0
    var switchState = false
    
    switch indexPath.section {
    case SETTINGS_SECTION:
        switchTag = settings[indexPath.row].tag
        if switchTag == 2 {
            if let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as? CustomTableViewCell {
                return customCell
            }
        }
        
        cell.textLabel?.text =  settings[indexPath.row].name
        switchTag = settings[indexPath.row].tag
        switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "metric")
        break
    case UPLOADS_SECTION:
        cell.textLabel?.text =  uploads[indexPath.row].name
        switchTag = uploads[indexPath.row].tag
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "strava")
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "cycling_analytics")
        }
        break
    case DEVICES_SECTION:
        let device = devices[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text =  device.name
        switchTag = device.tag
        if deviceManager!.savedDevices.firstIndex(of: device.id) != nil {
            switchState = true
        } else {
            switchState = false
        }
        
    default:
        break
        
    }
    
    let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    switchView.setOn(switchState, animated: true)
    switchView.tag = switchTag // for detect which row switch Changed
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.accessoryView = switchView
    return cell
}
```

Everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom UITableViewCell.

```
class SettingsCell : UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var textLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switchCtrl: UISwitch!
}
```